# tensorflow Conv2D layer input type issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I had a working PPO algorithm for the Cartpole environment from OpenAI Gym, and I wanted to tweak it to work for the CarRacing-v2 environment. I am having issues with having a wrong input type for the Conv2D layer.
I am on Ubuntu 22.04LTS, in a conda env with gym==0.26.0, tensorflow==2.10.0. The Observation from the CarRacing environment is an image (96,96,3) with type uint8.

This is the code where I only added the CNN layers with maxpooling and flatten.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten

INPUT_DIMS = (96, 96, 3)

# TODO add input dims and a few CNN parameters
class ActorNetwork(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, n_actions, fc1_dims=256, fc2_dims=256):
        super(ActorNetwork, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(8, (4,4), input_shape = INPUT_DIMS, activation = tf.nn.relu)
        self.pool1 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)
        self.conv2 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = tf.nn.relu)
        self.pool2 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)
        self.conv3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = tf.nn.relu)
        self.pool3 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)
        self.flatten = Flatten()

        self.fc1 = Dense(fc1_dims, activation='relu')
        self.fc2 = Dense(fc2_dims, activation='relu')
        self.fc3 = Dense(n_actions, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, state):
        # state = tf.cast(state, tf.float32)

        x = self.conv1(state)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.pool3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)

        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x


class CriticNetwork(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, fc1_dims=256, fc2_dims=256):
        super(CriticNetwork, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(8, (4,4), input_shape = INPUT_DIMS, activation = tf.nn.relu)
        self.pool1 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)
        self.conv2 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = tf.nn.relu)
        self.pool2 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)
        self.conv3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = tf.nn.relu)
        self.pool3 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        
        self.fc1 = Dense(fc1_dims, activation='relu')
        self.fc2 = Dense(fc2_dims, activation='relu')
        self.q = Dense(1, activation=None)

    def call(self, state):
        # state = tf.cast(state, tf.float32)

        x = self.conv1(state)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.pool3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        q = self.q(x)

        return q
```

The Actor and Critic are being called in this function

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from memory import PPOMemory
from networks import ActorNetwork, CriticNetwork

def choose_action(self, observation):
        state = tf.convert_to_tensor([observation])

        probs = self.actor(state)
        dist = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs)
        action = dist.sample()
        log_prob = dist.log_prob(action)
        value = self.critic(state)

        action = action.numpy()[0]
        value = value.numpy()[0]
        log_prob = log_prob.numpy()[0]

        return action, log_prob, value
```

Now the errors. When I dont have any retyping as you see currently this error shows

```
line 29, in call
    x = self.conv1(state)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d" "                 f"(type Conv2D).

cannot compute Conv2D as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int32 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Conv2D]

Call arguments received by layer "conv2d" "                 f"(type Conv2D):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 96, 96, 3), dtype=int32)
```

If I add retyping to my choose_action function: `state = tf.convert_to_tensor([observation], dtype=tf.float32)` this error shows

```
line 29, in call
    x = self.conv1(state)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d" "                 f"(type Conv2D).

Value for attr 'T' of uint8 is not in the list of allowed values: half, bfloat16, float, double, int32
        ; NodeDef: {{node Conv2D}}; Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID", "EXPLICIT"]; attr=explicit_paddings:list(int),default=[]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]; attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]> [Op:Conv2D]

Call arguments received by layer "conv2d" "                 f"(type Conv2D):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(5, 96, 96, 3), dtype=uint8)
```

It is only when I add `state = tf.cast(state, tf.float32)` to the start of each call() function that it works correctly but the learning is extremely slow. Do you have any ideas to why it is so slow and why don't the other retyping methods work?

I don't have a dedicated GPU so I am running tensorflow on a CPU.

Comment: TF does not compute gradients on discrete inputs: you need to use floating point numbers. I would also suggest to normalize your inputs between 0 and 1. For the slowness, assuming your install of TF is correct and can leverage a GPU, you can try to wrap your calls to `self.actor(state)` and `self.critic(state)` with a [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function).  This solution will only work well if the size of your inputs don't change across your training.

Comment: I don't have a GPU. I added @tf.function before each of the call function of the network and the speed practically didn't change. About the normalization... you are suggesting that I normalize the whole input image of 0-255 to be between 0-1? Wouldn't that process slow it down?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a matter of when to consider it as single function scripts.

Sample: Sample is a template you add prediction Fn and scapes you create a racer.
Easy is drive but staying on track all the time is the difficulty.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
ALE: 
EnvSpecEnvSpec(CarRacing-v2)
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

import os
from os.path import exists

import gym
import ale_py

import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Games Environments
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
env = gym.make("CarRacing-v2")  # , render_mode='human'
outputs = env.action_space
obs = env.reset()
observation, reward, done, info, prob = env.step([ -1.,  0.,  0. ])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
LONG_STEPS = 100000000000
n_outputs = 5

    # Discrete action       Continous action
    # Turn_left →           [ -1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
    # Turn_right→           [ +1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
    # Brake→                [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.8 ]
    # Accelerate→           [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.8 ]
    # Do-Nothing→           [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]

action_dataset = {
}

action_dataset["Turn_left"] =   [ -1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
action_dataset["Turn_right"] =  [ +1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
action_dataset["Brake"] =       [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.8 ]
action_dataset["Accelerate"] =  [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.8 ]
action_dataset["Do-Nothing"] =  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]

action_compute_dataset = {
}

### Can create mesh ###
action_compute_dataset[0] =     [ -1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
action_compute_dataset[1] =     [ +1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
action_compute_dataset[2] =     [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.8 ]
action_compute_dataset[3] =     [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.8 ]
action_compute_dataset[4] =     [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]

INPUT_DIMS = (96, 96, 3)

fig = plt.figure()
image = plt.imread( "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\cats_name\\train\\Symbols\\01.jpg" )
im = plt.imshow(image)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def animate( i ):
    action = [ -1.,  0.,  0. ]
    scores = 0
    observation, reward, done, info, prob = env.step(action)
    env.render()

    if done:
        observation, info = env.reset(return_info=True)
        action = [ -1.,  0.,  0. ]
        scores = 0

    action = random_action( 1 )
    observation, reward, done, info, prob = env.step(action_compute_dataset[action])

    DATA = tf.constant( observation, shape=( 1, 1, INPUT_DIMS[0], INPUT_DIMS[1], INPUT_DIMS[2] ) )
    LABEL = tf.constant( action, shape=( 1, 1, 1 ), dtype=tf.float32 )
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( (DATA, LABEL) )
    history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=1 ,validation_data=(dataset), callbacks=[custom_callback])

    im.set_array( observation )
    plt.xlabel( str(action), fontsize=22 )
    plt.ylabel( "scores: " + str( scores ) )
    plt.show()

    return im,
    
def random_action(action): 
        
    temp = tf.random.normal([n_outputs], 1, 0.2, tf.float32)
    temp_2 = tf.constant( tf.ones(n_outputs, tf.float32) * 48, dtype=tf.float32 )
    temp = tf.math.multiply( temp, temp_2, name="Multiply" )
    # action_compute_dataset[tf.math.argmax(temp).numpy()]

    return tf.math.argmax(temp).numpy()
    
def create_model():

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=INPUT_DIMS),
    
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (4,4), input_shape = INPUT_DIMS, activation = tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),


    ])
            
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
    model.summary()

    return model


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # if( logs['loss'] <= 0.2 ):
            # self.model.stop_training = True
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.95 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DATA = tf.constant( observation, shape=( 1, 1, INPUT_DIMS[0], INPUT_DIMS[1], INPUT_DIMS[2] ) )
LABEL = tf.constant( [0], shape=( 1, 1, 1 ), dtype=tf.float32 )

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( (DATA, LABEL) )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=1 ,validation_data=(dataset), callbacks=[custom_callback])

while LONG_STEPS > 0:
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50, blit=True)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This code does not work without your images and even if it worked it needs a dataset and I am using PPO which trains on the go from the data we give it.